# C++ max of an array using recursion issue

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I have this program that finds the largest integer in an array using recursion, but it keeps returning the last number entered no matter what the value instead of the largest number. How do i fix this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int maximum(int digits[], int size, int largest, int i);

void main()
{
  const int size = 3;
  int digits[size];
  int n = 0, x = 0;

  for(int a = 0; a < size; a++)
  {
      cout << "Enter an integer <" << ++x << " out of " << size << ">: ";
      cin >> digits[n];
  }

  cout << "\nThe largest digit is, " << maximum(digits, size, 0, 0) << ", thank you!\n";
  cout << endl;
}


int maximum(int digits[], int size, int largest, int i)
{
  if ( i < size )
  {
      if ( largest < digits[i])
          largest = digits[i];

      maximum( digits, size, largest, i + 1);
  }
  return largest;
}
```

Comment: Have you carefully traced what it's doing on each line as it runs and compared it to what you expect (e.g., with a debugger)?

Comment: I have and it seemed right to me thats why im stuck

Comment: @beginnerjohn, If every line of execution seems right to you as it's executing (all variables have the expected value, the line is the line you expected to run next), then the program is working as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use the index variable properly in `main()`

```
  for(int a = 0; a < size; a++)
  {
      cout << "Enter an integer <" << ++x << " out of " << size << ">: ";
      cin >> digits[a];//-->Use the index varible correctly.
  }
```

---

```
int maximum(int digits[], int size, int largest, int i)
{
  if(i==size-1)
    return digits[i]; //The base case is specified here.
  if ( i < size )
  {
      int temp= maximum( digits, size, largest, i + 1);
      if ( digits[i] < temp)
          largest =temp;
      else
         largest=digits[i];

  }
  return largest;
}
```

Please check out the changes. Carefully read the code. You will understand your mistakes.

When designing recursion think of few things first-

- The base condition. (This stops the recursion).
- The recursive step. (Where you will calculate something based on previous calculation)
- Combine step- You have to combine them (value at this stage and value got from recusive step) to get the correct answer. This step is not required in some cases.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot more sense

Comment: one question, why would i use if(i==size - 1) not if(i==size) or if(i>size)? just so i can better understand the code.

Comment: @beginnerjohn.: `i==size` is not used because then you can't index into the array. why not `i>size`? as that is never required in this case. I don't have to check for`i>size` if I can break the recursion with `i==size` and after all we are increasing `i` by a value of `1` at each step. So never the value will be`>size` without having the value `size`.

Comment: ok i think i get it im still a little iffy so im going to study this code a little more recursions are still tricky for me. thanks.

Comment: It's not really necessary to pass largest around. The only time it would come into play is for an empty list.

Comment: @jaket.:Yes that's right. Actually my intention was to give a correct answer changing minimum. Although I think empty list can also be detected using the `size` field. Give ideas if you have - I will incorporate it in the post to make it accurate.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `return maximum( digits, size, largest, i + 1);`

[Live example](https://ideone.com/Ihbe5E).

Comment: the initial problem was that the program just returned the last value entered no matter the value, not the largest element in the array. Adding return did not change anything. the problem has already been fixed

Comment: @beginnerjohn: Have you follow the Live example link ? I have only added the missing return and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
int biggestOne(int integerArray[], int lengthOfArray, int max)
{
    if (lengthOfArray==0) return max;
    if (max < integerArray[lengthOfArray-1]) max = integerArray[lengthOfArray-1];
    return biggestOne(integerArray,lengthOfArray-1,max); 
}

int main()
{
    int array[] = {7,2,9,10,1};
    int arrSize = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); //returns length of the array

    cout <<"Biggest number in the array: " << biggestOne(array,arrSize,0) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```